# How to check all the available arguments in a R function

Tags: r

For example, when we type `?plot`, we got:

```
plot(x, y, ...)
... Arguments to be passed to methods
```

My question is how to see all the arguments hidden in `...`.

Comment: If you want to see an enumeration of what arguments are _possible_, you need to look at the documentation for specific methods, as it says in the docs you quote. For example, look at `?plot.default`. And all of those docs (including the page you quote from) will include a link to the docs for `par`, showing a very long list of possible arguments.

Comment: Thanks,@joran. `plot.default` seems helpful. But how about any others. For example, `dplyr::full_join()`. How can I know the list of arguments behind `...`?

Comment: @DavidZ Unless you want to look at the code for the function in each case and follow the evaluation path to see what exactly will be called, your only real recourse is to rely on the documentation. In the case of `full_join` if you examine the code I think you'll find that `...` is currently not used.

Comment: ...often authors will include `...` as an argument defensively in case they need to pass additional arguments on later in new versions. Better documentation will indicate if it is currently unused or not, but not always.

Comment: But why do you need this?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342906/how-to-check-all-the-arguments-of-a-function-in-r