# plot() function default parameters

Tags: r, plot

Usually when we type `par()` on console it will give a list of all default parameters of `par` function. But what about `plot`, when I try `plot()` it gives an error. What is different about functions such as this.

Does it have something to do with it being generic function. Please point to any resource I can read up on this.

Comment: `help("par")`: "par can be used to set or **query** graphical parameters." `help("plot")`: "Generic function for plotting of R objects."

Comment: A similar question has been discussed in the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38958236/4770166

Answer (score 3):

Example, using `args()` and `formalArgs()` or `formals()` function to know the list of arguments in a function.

I. Using `args()`

```
    args(qplot)
    # function (x, y = NULL, ..., data, facets = NULL, margins = FALSE, 
    #     geom = "auto", xlim = c(NA, NA), ylim = c(NA, NA), log = "", 
    #     main = NULL, xlab = deparse(substitute(x)), ylab = deparse(substitute(y)), 
    #     asp = NA, stat = NULL, position = NULL) 
    # NULL
```

II. Using `formalArgs()`

```
    formalArgs(qplot)
    #  [1] "x"        "y"        "..."      "data"     "facets"   "margins"  "geom"     "xlim"     "ylim"     "log"     
    # [11] "main"     "xlab"     "ylab"     "asp"      "stat"     "position"
```

III. Using `formals()`

```
   formals(qplot)
   # $x


   # $y
   NULL

   # $...


   # $data


   # $facets
   # NULL

   # $margins
   # [1] FALSE

   # $geom
   # [1] "auto"

   # $xlim
   # c(NA, NA)

   # $ylim
   # c(NA, NA)

   # $log
   # [1] ""

   # $main
   # NULL

   # $xlab
   # deparse(substitute(x))

   # $ylab
   # deparse(substitute(y))

   # $asp
   # [1] NA

   # $stat
   # NULL

   # $position
   # NULL
```

Then to check, type `?qplot` in R Console and check in the help page whether it has the same arguments.

IV. Analysis on `par()` and some other similar kind of functions like `options()`

```
  class(par)
  # [1] "function"
  class(par())
  # [1] "list"
  class(plot)
  # [1] "function"
  class(plot())
  # Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  #   argument "x" is missing, with no default

  names(par())
  #  [1] "xlog"      "ylog"      "adj"       "ann"       "ask"       "bg"        "bty"       "cex"       "cex.axis" 
  # [10] "cex.lab"   "cex.main"  "cex.sub"   "cin"       "col"       "col.axis"  "col.lab"   "col.main"  "col.sub"  
  # [19] "cra"       "crt"       "csi"       "cxy"       "din"       "err"       "family"    "fg"        "fig"      
  # [28] "fin"       "font"      "font.axis" "font.lab"  "font.main" "font.sub"  "lab"       "las"       "lend"     
  # [37] "lheight"   "ljoin"     "lmitre"    "lty"       "lwd"       "mai"       "mar"       "mex"       "mfcol"    
  # [46] "mfg"       "mfrow"     "mgp"       "mkh"       "new"       "oma"       "omd"       "omi"       "page"     
  # [55] "pch"       "pin"       "plt"       "ps"        "pty"       "smo"       "srt"       "tck"       "tcl"      
  # [64] "usr"       "xaxp"      "xaxs"      "xaxt"      "xpd"       "yaxp"      "yaxs"      "yaxt"      "ylbias"
```

`par()` is a functions which has list of parameters, whichever parameter you specify those will be stored inside `par()` and in turn will effect the plot, the rest parameter has its own default set.

Similar kind of function `options()`

```
  class(options)
  # [1] "function"
  class(options())
  # [1] "list"

  head(names(options()))    # List is bigger, just printing head of it
  # [1] "add.smooth"          "browserNLdisabled"   "CBoundsCheck"        "check.bounds"        "citation.bibtex.max"
  # [6] "continue"
```

Calling `options()` like `par()`

```
  options()
  $add.smooth
  # [1] TRUE

  # $browserNLdisabled
  # [1] FALSE

  # $CBoundsCheck
  # [1] FALSE

  # $check.bounds
  # [1] FALSE

  # $citation.bibtex.max
  # [1] 1

  # $continue
  # [1] "+ "

  # $contrasts
  #         unordered           ordered 
  # "contr.treatment"      "contr.poly" 

  # $defaultPackages
  # [1] "datasets"  "utils"     "grDevices" "graphics"  "stats"     "methods"  

  # $demo.ask
  # [1] "default"

  # $deparse.cutoff
  # [1] 60

  # $device
  # function (width, height, pointsize, record, rescale, xpinch, 
  #     ypinch, bg, canvas, gamma, xpos, ypos, buffered, title, restoreConsole, 
  #     clickToConfirm, fillOddEven, family = "", antialias) 
  # {
  #     check <- Sys.getenv("_R_CHECK_SCREEN_DEVICE_", "")
  #     msg <- "screen devices should not be used in examples etc"
  #     if (identical(check, "stop")) 
  #         stop(msg, domain = NA)
  #     else if (identical(check, "warn")) 
  #         warning(msg, immediate. = TRUE, noBreaks. = TRUE, domain = NA)
  #     new <- list()
  #     if (!missing(width)) 
  #         new$width <- as.double(width)
  #     if (!missing(height)) 
  #         new$height <- as.double(height)
  #     if (!missing(pointsize)) 
  #         new$pointsize <- as.double(pointsize)
  #     if (!missing(record)) 
  #         new$record <- record 
  #     if (!missing(rescale)) 
  #         new$rescale <- rescale
  #     if (!missing(xpinch)) 
  #         new$xpinch <- as.double(xpinch)
  #     if (!missing(ypinch)) 
  #         new$ypinch <- as.double(ypinch)
  #     if (!missing(bg)) 
  #         new$bg <- bg
  #     if (!missing(canvas)) 
  #         new$canvas <- canvas
  #     if (!missing(gamma)) 
  #         new$gamma <- gamma
  #     if (!missing(xpos)) 
  #         new$xpos <- as.integer(xpos)
  #     if (!missing(ypos)) 
  #         new$ypos <- as.integer(ypos)
  #     if (!missing(buffered)) 
  #         new$buffered <- buffered
  #     if (!missing(title)) 
  #         new$title <- title
  #     if (!missing(restoreConsole)) 
  #         new$restoreConsole <- restoreConsole
  #     if (!missing(clickToConfirm)) 
  #         new$clickToConfirm <- clickToConfirm
  #     if (!missing(fillOddEven)) 
  #         new$fillOddEven <- fillOddEven
  #     if (!missing(antialias)) 
  #         new$antialias <- match.arg(antialias, aa.win)
  #     d <- check.options(new = new, envir = .WindowsEnv, name.opt = ".Windows.Options", 
  #         reset = FALSE, assign.opt = FALSE)
  #     rescale <- match(d$rescale, c("R", "fit", "fixed"))
  #     if (is.na(rescale)) 
  #         stop("invalid value for 'rescale'")
  #     antialias <- pmatch(d$antialias, aa.win)
  #     invisible(.External(C_devga, "", d$width, d$height, d$pointsize, 
  #         d$record, rescale, d$xpinch, d$ypinch, d$canvas, d$gamma, 
  #         d$xpos, d$ypos, d$buffered, .PSenv, d$bg, d$restoreConsole, 
  #         d$title, d$clickToConfirm, d$fillOddEven, family, antialias))
  # }
  # <bytecode: 0x0000000015330530>
  # <environment: namespace:grDevices>

  # $device.ask.default
  # [1] FALSE

  # $digits
  # [1] 7

  # $echo
  # [1] TRUE

  # $editor
  # [1] "internal"

  # $encoding
  # [1] "native.enc"

  # $example.ask
  # [1] "default"

  # $expressions
  # [1] 5000

  # $help.search.types
  # [1] "vignette" "demo"     "help"    

  # $help.try.all.packages
  # [1] FALSE

  # $help_type
  # [1] "html"

  # $HTTPUserAgent
  # [1] "R (3.3.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32 x86_64 mingw32)"

  # $install.packages.compile.from.source
  # [1] "interactive"

  # $internet.info
  # [1] 2

  # $keep.source
  # [1] TRUE

  # $keep.source.pkgs
  # [1] FALSE

  # $lme4.summary.cor.max
  # [1] 12

  # $locatorBell
  # [1] TRUE

  # $mailer
  # [1] "mailto"

  # $max.print
  # [1] 99999

  # $menu.graphics
  # [1] TRUE

  # $mgcv.vc.logrange
  # [1] 25

  # $na.action
  # [1] "na.omit"

  # $nwarnings
  # [1] 50

  # $OutDec
  # [1] "."

  # $pager
  # [1] "internal"

  # $papersize
  # [1] "letter"

  # $pdfviewer
  # [1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/open.exe"

  # $pkgType
  # [1] "both"

  # $prompt
  # [1] "> "

  # $repos
  #                                        CRAN                                    CRANextra 
  # "https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CRAN"        "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin" 

  # $scipen
  # [1] 0

  # $show.coef.Pvalues
  # [1] TRUE

  # $show.error.messages
  # [1] TRUE

  # $show.signif.stars
  # [1] TRUE

  # $str
  # $str$strict.width
  # [1] "no"

  # $str$digits.d
  # [1] 3

  # $str$vec.len
  # [1] 4


  # $str.dendrogram.last
  # [1] "`"

  # $stringsAsFactors
  # [1] TRUE

  # $timeout
  # [1] 60

  # $ts.eps
  # [1] 1e-05

  # $ts.S.compat
  # [1] FALSE

  # $unzip
  # [1] "internal"

  # $useFancyQuotes
  # [1] TRUE

  # $verbose
  # [1] FALSE

  # $warn
  # [1] 0

  # $warning.length
  # [1] 1000

  # $width
  # [1] 130

  # $windowsTimeouts
  # [1] 100 500
```

Comment: That answers how to find arguments, but why is `plot` function special in that it doesnt give list of default parameters when you use command `plot()`

Comment: @emperorspride: Some functions uses `UseMethod` inside it. Plot uses `plot` method. There the difference comes. WIll get back here soon.

Comment: @emperorspride188 To understand please refer pdf called `R Language Definitions` stored as `R-lang.pdf` inside R Console. `Go to Help -> Manuals(in PDF) -> R Language Definitions and see Chapter 4 Functions of few pages which has all description.`