# What does "... other arguments for plotting." mean in help of a function in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am looking for parameters that I could control size or text of, for example, main title in [this function](https://github.com/davidcarslaw/deweather/blob/master/man/plotPD.Rd) `"plotPD"`.
I already tried `main="The Sine Function"` but it does not change. 
I check the help of function but it is silent about plotting parameters, ending with

> "...   other arguments for plotting."

I could not also find my answer [in a old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342906/how-to-check-all-the-arguments-of-a-function-in-r).

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: This can mean different things for different packages/function. If you are asking specifically about the `plotPD()` function, then you should make that clear in your question. Unfortunately there is no requirement that a package provides "complete" documentation so when the documentation is incomplete, you sometimes need to look at the source code of the function to see what it's doing.

Comment: Did you just want to add a title to your plot? That package seem to use ggplot as a plotting foundation. You can probably just use `+labs(main="The Sine Function")` to set the title like any other ggplot object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You answer at least made it clear to me  that it is not straight forward to find these parameters. Regarding function, I added the name in my question. What confused me is that I want to put this function in lapply. like this plots <- lapply(variables, plotPD, dat = mod_no2, ylab = ylab, 
                ylim = ylim)+labs(main="The Sine Function")


do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange, c(plots, nrow = nrow))

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. I would change the question to ask about what you are really tying to accomplish (set title, change y limits?) rather than an unanswerable question about interpreting vague package documentation. But code in your question so it can be formatted, not in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The key point you said was it uses ggplot. I made changes in the source.